# How to automate the scenario of different user take action on same prospect?

Tags: jmeter

In my application there are different types of users RM, AAM & SM,
one or more prospect come firstly to RM bucket, RM take action on it by selecting one / more the prospects (Prospect ID are unique here). after action of RM same prospects moved (not display for RM login) to AAM bucket. AAM select the one or more prospects & take action & so on.

How can I automate the scenario, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In order to automate complex functional scenarios, it is very important that we are using JMeter controllers to their full potential.

We implement modular approach and achieve reusability in our scripts using **Modular controller**.

We can use **IF controllers** to perform different actions on different conditions.

Other controllers that you might find useful for your scenario are **InterLeave controller, Switch Controller and While controller.**